# How to sync Laravel Application with Email Server

Tags: php, laravel, email, synchronization

I am trying to Create a Mail Box for each user and each user account will be connected to his email(Gmail, Outlook, etc). Now I am trying to connect email in real-time whenever they receive an email they also get in their mailbox. I can get receive the email through **IMAP** but it is not real-time I have to look for a new email after a specific time. I am looking for a package or library that can do it easily for me or any other solution. After searching I get only one solution which is IMAP and I also implemented it but now I need another solution that fits exactly. If anyone has any idea pls share. and what if I set up my own custom email server with a custom domain so how can I create such functionality with Laravel.

> Why I am doing all this?

beceause I want this real time when ever user receive email his ticket will be created on behalf of email it does not need to wait until IMAP fetch and then ticket will be created or displayed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use something like [EmailEngine](https://emailengine.app/) that handles all the IMAP connections and new message detections?

Answer (score 0):

You do not really have any other option besides IMAP, unless you want to pair with specific services like Exchange Web Services.

PHP has a very comprehensive set of functions regarding IMAP. I would suggest checking it out. Unfortunately, there is not really anything you can do from within PHP to prevent having to poll.

My suggestion is checking in the background if new mails have arrived. For example by checking from within a cronjob. That way you don't have to initiate a new connection to an IMAP server every time a users visits the page.

[IMAP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php)

Comment: hey, @Rien Bijil I have edited the question with further description can you review it one more time and see if you can help now.

Comment: IMAP does not have pub/sub construction, receiving mails in actual real-time is not possible. You will have to poll the server.